# Is the r-value parameter really an l-value parameter inside the function scope?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, lis

I have found the following snippet in a code implementing a `list` class

```
    void push_front( const T & x ) { insert( begin( ), x ); }

    void push_front( T && x ) { insert( begin( ), std::move( x ) );}
```

Now I know that if I have a function taking a parameter as an `r-value`, that parameter will be `l-value` in the scope of the function (Isn't that right?).

So I can replace the previous snippet by

```
void push_front( const T & x ) { insert( begin( ), x ); }

void push_front( T && x ) { push_front( x );}
```

The first question: Am I right?

The second one: By considering that the `r-value` parameter in the first snippet is an `l-value` parameter inside the second function, Will `std::move( x )` cast `x` from `l-value` to `r-value` and the function `push_front()` call the `r-value` version of the function `insert()` or what?

An edit::

This is how `insert()` is implemented

```
    iterator insert( iterator itr, const T & x )
    {
        Node *p = itr.current;
        theSize++;
        return { p->prev = p->prev->next = new Node{ x, p->prev, p } };
    }


    iterator insert( iterator itr, T && x )
    {
        Node *p = itr.current;
        theSize++;
        return { p->prev = p->prev->next = new Node{ std::move( x ), p->prev, p } };
    }
```

The definition of `Node`

```
struct Node
    {
        private:
        T data;
        Node *prev;
        Node *next;

        Node( const T & d = T{ }, Node * p = nullptr,
        Node * n = nullptr )//It's possible because of const
        :data{ d }, prev{ p }, next{ n } { }

        Node( T && d, Node * p = nullptr, Node * n = nullptr )
        : data{ std::move( d ) }, prev{ p }, next{ n } { }
    };
```

Comment: Your suggested replacement will copy the argument instead of moving from it as the first example does. Whether you are right to make the change depends on whether that is the behaviour you want ...

Comment: Almost everything you want to know can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics

Comment: @M.M I meant if `std::move(x)` converts x to `rvalue`, then  `push_front(T&& )` will be called instead of `push_front(const T& )`

Comment: @M.M If I have only two versions of `push_front()` (i.e) `push_front(T&& )` and `push_front(const T& )`, hence my object won't be copied and my replacement will be better, won't it?

Comment: @anonymous your replacement would copy the object instead of moving it.  The code `push_front( std::move(x) )` moves the object and `push_front(x)` does not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a function taking a parameter as an r-value, that parameter will be l-value in the scope of the function

Yes. In general, all rvalue reference variables are lvalues, function parameters or not.

> So I can replace the previous snippet by ...

Yes, but then `push_front(T &&x)` will copy `x` instead of moving it.

> Will `std::move( x )` cast x from l-value to r-value and the function `push_front()`call the r-value version of the function `insert()`

Yes.

Comment: Don't you mean you will copy instead of move for the second answer?

Comment: If I have only two versions of push_front() (i.e) `push_front(T&& )` and `push_front(const T& )`, hence my object won't be copied and my replacement will be better, won't it?

Comment: _In general, all rvalue references are lvalues, function parameters or not._ That's false. A call to a function returning rvalue reference is not an lvalue.

Comment: @anonymous `push_front(const T& )` copies the object. Since your `push_front(T&& )` uses `push_front(const T& )`, it will also copy.

Comment: @yurikilochek I meant rvalue reference variables, edited to make it more clear. But technically the result of such a call is an rvalue of some non-reference type (not an rvalue reference).

Comment: how does `push_front(const T& )` copy the object while it takes a constant reference to it

Comment: @anonymous Merely passing the object to `push_front` doesn't copy it. Calling `insert( begin( ), x );` does.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `insert( begin( ), x )` function has only two versions `insert( it, T&& )` and `insert( it, const T& )`

Comment: @anonymous Yes, the first one moves the object and the second one copies it. Your `push_front(const T& )` always calls the second one.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat But what I know the first one moves the object and the second one takes a reference to it (the variable itself without any copying). Plz, more explanation about that.

Comment: @anonymous Merely passing an object to it doesn't copy it (neither does merely passing something to `insert( it, T&& )` moves it). Copying/moving happens in the function body. (You didn't show how `insert` is implemented, so I can't know if it really copies/moves anything or not. But if the guy who wrote that code has some common sense, one of them moves the object and the other copies it.)

Comment: I put the functions `insert()` of the class

Comment: @anonymous Doing `new Node{ x, p->prev, p } ` copies `x`.

Comment: It doesn't at ALL. Because it has two `ctor`s. one of them takes `r-value` and the other takes a constant ref.

Comment: @anonymous Simply passing an object to a const reference doesn't copy it, yes. But I'm certain that the body of the constructor taking the const reference copies that reference. Add the definition of `class Node` to the question and we can check that.

Comment: @anonymous Yeah, here's your copy: `:data{ d }`.